# Is continuous a function if and only if preserves order?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-theory

I'm trying to prove that. Let $(X,\leq)$ a partial ordered set, with the associated topology formed by the subsets $U$:

$ x \in U$ and $ y \leq x \Rightarrow y \in U$

Then a function $f$ is continuous if and only if it preserves the order, i.e, $x\leq y \Rightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)$.

Any help?

Comment: Already for $X=\Bbb R$ there are plenty of counterexamples, such as $f(x)=-x$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @GregMartin the topology defined by Peter is not the same as the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. For example, the set $(-\infty,a]$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ with this topology. The functions $f(x)=-x$ and $f(x)=x^2$ are not continuous in this topology.

Comment: @GregMartin: Neither of those is a counterexample: for $\Bbb R$ the topology in question has the sets $(\leftarrow,x]$ as a base.

Comment: thanks, I now agree my earlier comment isn't relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be partially ordered sets and $f\colon X\to Y$ a map.

First, assume that $f$ is increasing, and let $U$ be an open set in $Y$. Let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ and let $y\in X$ such that $y\leq x$. As $f$ is increasing, then $f(y)\leq f(x)$, thus $f(y)\in U$ by definition of the open sets in $Y$. Then $y\in f^{-1}(U)$ and this shows that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Hence, $f$ is continuous.

Conversely, assume that $f$ is continuous and let $x,y\in X$ such that $y\leq x$. Let
$$
U= \{z\in Y \ \colon \ z\leq f(x)\}.
$$
This is an open set in $Y$ because if $z\in U$ and $w\leq z$ then $w\leq z\leq f(x)$ and $w\in U$. Thus $U$ is an open neighborhood of $f(x)$ in $Y$ and by continuity, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighorhood of $x$ in $X$. As $y\leq x$ we have that $y\in f^{-1}(U)$ and consequently, $f(y)\in U$. By definition of $U$ this means that $f(y)\leq f(x)$, which shows that $f$ is increasing.

**Remark.** We don't need the sets $X$ and $Y$ to be partially ordered but only preordered. That is, the relation $\leq$ only needs to be refletive and transitive, but not necessarily antisymmetric.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me a lot!